# SSRS server impersonation error - Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

We are trying to implement RLS on SSRS reports so that the user viewing the reports gets to see only records he is permitted to.

For this purpose we are required to use the following settings while connecting to the data source (that is an SQL-server DB), with impersonation enabled:

[image: DB Connection settings]

When the checkbox is unchecked, the database connects normally and all reports utilizing the source are working normally.

However, when we try to enable impersonation and try to connect, it hits with the following error:

[image: Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'myDomain/myUsername', error code 0x534.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following settings. If you want to use user credentials to connect the data Source.

[image]

In Other ways you can change the "Type of credentials to SQL Server if you want to Users to use SQL Server Authentication.

Comment: Will this ask the user for credentials every time he tries to view a report?

Comment: @PratikBhavsar - Yes